# How to create a copy of a project to experiment with

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I often desire to modify a copy of a code, not the original, to experiment with. I usually just create another project with a different name copying and pasting the code. Anyway now I am working on a bigger project involving 5 files. So I am creating a new folder with a different name ( inside "Projects" Visual Studio 2010 ), copying all the content of my project's folder in it, open it from visual studio and then rename the .sln file with the same name of the new folder. Anything better to suggest ? Am I making any error ?

Comment: Try version control system, like git. It was a miracle discovery for me.

Comment: With a source control system in place you could experiment with code and then restore to the original version.

Comment: [github has a nice intro to git](http://learn.github.com/p/index.html) which you may find useful. if you're learning to program you're going to want to learn about version control at some point anyway.

Comment: Once you've started to look into version control, as mentioned by the above comments, read up on branching. You can then create a branch from the main one, experiment with that and either revert back to the original main branch, or even merge the changes of the new one with main.